# How to prevent the Opening of a file instead of a route in an Angular App on Android?

Tags: android, angularjs

My Setup is an Angular App running on Android using AEMM and cordova. The App has a menu of which the following code is a small part:

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="route in route.children">
        <a ng-href="{{ route.url }}">
            {{ route.label | translate }}
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

When I inspect the output on a webbrowser on my local development system the generated HTML looks like this:

```
<ul>
    <!-- ngRepeat: route in route.children -->
    <li ng-repeat="route in route.children" class="ng-scope">
        <a ng-href="foo/bar" class="ng-binding" href="foo/bar">
            Some Label
        </a>
    </li>
    <!-- end ngRepeat: route in route.children -->
</ul>
```

These links work as expected in any webbrowser and on iOS. The App routes to `foo/bar`. However on Android (6) the link is somehow interpreted as a link to a file, which of course cannot be found leading to an error:

> ### Webpage not availbale
>
> The webpage at
>   **file:///storage/emulated/0/.../foo/bar** could not be loaded because:
>
> net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It came down to a rather embarrasing finding: The router was not configured to run in HTML5 mode, so the correct routes needed a leading `#/`. So it was rather a question of "why did it work in browsers and on IOS?"

Nevertheless. It's solved now.